Xquery used for counting working days between two dates, but wrong results
In Informatica I got this Xquery line of code build in an Application Integration process:
fn:sum(for $j in 0 to fn:days-from-duration(xs:date($temp.t_laatsteLeverDatum) - fn:current-date()) 
return if (fn:day-from-date(fn:current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', $j, 'D'))) < 6) then 1 else 0)

It counts the number of working days between today and a given date called t_laatsteLeverDatum (last delivery date).
Today is 2024-10-25 and the latest delivery date is set on 2024-11-06. When using above line of code the result should be 13 days minus 4 weekend days = 9. But whatever I do, the result I get is 5.
Then I tried:
fn:count(
  for $i in 0 to fn:days-from-duration(xs:date($temp.t_dateRequestedJDE) - fn:current-date())
  let $day := fn:current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', $i, 'D'))
  where fn:day-from-date($day) lt 6
  return $day
)

But this still results in 5 instead of 9. What do I wrong and or how do I get the right number of working days between now and a given delivery date?

Looks to me like you're trying to count days that are 6 or less away from fn:current-date() here:
$temp.t_laatsteLeverDatum) - fn:current-date()

or here
let $day := fn:current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', $i, 'D'))
where fn:day-from-date($day) lt 6

So you nowwhere check the weekday, which is what you'd need to compare with 6. Hope this helps.
Next have a look at this post.

Thanks for the quick reply, I will dive into that other post. Counting days that are 6 days away from current date? That should clarify why, when using this functionality, orders with a date further than 6 days from now are processed. But that 6 should stand for Saturday so every day I check needs to be 1 till 5 (Monday till Friday) and then add 1 else 0 .....

"It should" - but what do you compare to the 6? You compare the difference xs:date($temp.t_dateRequestedJDE) - fn:current-date(). This does not represent the weekday. This will return... DIFFERENCE in days. So you will get 1 each time the DIFFERENCE between the  t_dateRequestedJDE and current-date is less then 6. So you can get any value between 0 and 5 and nothing else. Ever. What you SHOULD be comparing to 6 is the DAY OF THE WEEK NUMBER. But your code never calculates the number of the day in the week.

thanks for your first remark and explanation afterwards ... this triggered me and after some testing I found out, as you state above that I did not compare day of the week number but day of the month versus a then meaningless value 6 .... I modified the code and I do get that 9 instead of 5 in above given example. I do not have the space in this reaction here to put my modified code however?

Update this thread with one more answer. Simply: answer your own question! :)

@Maciejg, thanks for your last reply. I was once told that it's not common for topic starters to answer their topics that way, that's why.
The code I use now is:
let $referenceDate := xs:date("2024-01-01")
let $daysInWeek := 7
let $startDate := fn:current-date()
let $endDate := xs:date($temp.t_laatsteLeverDatum) (: or $temp.t_dateRequestedJDE :)

return if (
    fn:sum(
        for $i in 0 to fn:days-from-duration($endDate - $startDate)
        let $currentDate := $startDate + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', $i, 'D'))
        let $daysSinceReference := fn:days-from-duration($currentDate - $referenceDate)
        let $dayOfWeek := (1 + ($daysSinceReference mod $daysInWeek)) (: Convert to 1=Monday, ..., 7=Sunday :)
        return if ($dayOfWeek >= 1 and $dayOfWeek <= 5) then 1 else 0
    ) <= 3
) then 1 else 0

This code gave the expected 9 instead of 5. Unfortunately the simpler function fn:day-of-week() was not available in the environment I am working in.
Thanks for thinking along and your reactions and kind regards,
Aad


Unfortunately the simpler function fn:day-of-week() was not available in the environment I am working in.

That's because functx:day-of-week() is part of the FunctX XQuery Library Module, which you have to import in your environment.
Loosely based on this function you could use the following query, no matter the dates you enter:
count(
  for $i in 0 to fn:days-from-duration(xs:date("2024-11-06") - xs:date("2024-10-25"))
  return
  (1 to 5)[
    fn:days-from-duration(
      xs:date("2024-10-25") + xs:dayTimeDuration(`P{$i}D`) - xs:date("1901-01-06")
    ) mod 7
  ]
)

Less code and, after having measured, a bit faster as well.

xs:date("1901-01-06"), as used by functx:day-of-week(), was a sunday and is used as a reference.
With (1 to 5) you limit the result to working days only, because 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday ... and 6 = Saturday after all.

